# @property AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'setter' - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

I have a script that goes like this

```
w = False

class A(object):
    @property
    def is_w(self):
        global w
        return w

    @w.setter
    def is_w(self, value):
        global w
        w = value
        self.listen(value)

    def listen(self,w_):
        if w_:
            print("worked!")
            w = False
   def value_change(self):
        global w
        w = True
```

I need the listen() function to run whenever the w value becomes true and stops when it's false again. the w value changes when another function changes it for example here the value_change() function
However I get this error `AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'setter'`

Comment: It's rather anti-pattern to have an object property returning a global value.

Comment: The real anti-pattern is using hidden side-effects to control program flow.

Answer (score 1):

`@property` transforms the function that it's applied on into a property object. That object has the `setter` attribute that you need. So the `setter` needs to be annotated with `<function with @property>.setter`:

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def is_w(self):
        global w
        return w

    @is_w.setter  # here
    def set_w(self, value):  # rename this method to a different name
        global w
        w = value
        self.listen(value)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, unfortunately I tried this approach and when the value became true the listen() function didn't start